# suneditor-react Typescript getContent is not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, suneditor

I'm using **suneditor-react** with **typescript**. I want to **get the content** of the editor **to create a PDF**. But the problem is when I try to access a ref of the SunEditor, I got the following error

```
Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SunEditorReactProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

Further, I couldn't find a `getContents()` prop as well in the `SunEditorReactProps`. But it is in thier example page.
[image]

Please give your ideas.

[sunediotr-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/suneditor-react)

[suneditor example page](http://suneditor.com/sample/html/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am the author of the SunEditor React Component you can learn how to attach ref to the suneditor react component (in typescript) [here](https://github.com/mkhstar/suneditor-react#about-core).

Answer (score 0):

1. Import SuneditorCore

```
import SunEditorCore from "suneditor/src/lib/core";
```

2)Declare  and set value of given variable

```
private suneditor1!:SunEditorCore;
this.suneditor1=suneditor.create('sample', {
            
});
```

3)Call suneditor functions

```
const savedata=this.suneditor1.getContents(true);
```